# C# Enter Data Into Texbox

Tags: c#, textbox

How can I put the contents of a string into the display of a textbox using C#?

Thanks.

Comment: You should accept an answer if any of the following is a solution to your question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
string a = "My Message";


textbox1.Text = a;
```

Answer (score 7):

Set the Text property.

```
textBox1.Text = "Hello, world!";
```

Answer (score 0):

The Textbox.Text property contains the string of the Textbox.

```
String s = "Hello world";
// To set the text of a textbox
tbString.Text = s;
// To append string to the textbox
tbString.Text += s;
```